# jQuery select/unselect all siblings

Tags: jquery, select, checkbox

I´m trying to select all siblings when first is checked.. and then if it´s unchecked all siblings should be unselected.

but I can´t work it out so any pointers are welcome :)

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>           
    <ul>
    <li><input id="checkall" type="checkbox" />Select all</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" />Child 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" />Child 2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" />Child 3</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" />Child 4</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
            //clicking the first checkbox should check or uncheck all checkboxes in that element 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkall').click(function(){
        if ($(this).closest('ul').find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false)) {
            $(this).closest('ul').find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', true)
        }
        else ($(this).closest('ul').find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', true)); {
            $(this).closest('ul').find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false)
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.attr('checked', false)` will set the 'false` value to checked property of the element and not return a boolean value. You can simplify you code like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkall').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('ul').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

Comment: related question: I set a new class when checked but the checkbox i click on does not get the class.. ? $(this).closest('ul').find('span').toggleClass('checked');

Comment: Try this `$(this).closest('ul').find('span').toggleClass('checked', this.checked)`;

Comment: In the question there will be a checkbox to mark it as ans answer and then submit.

Comment: How do I get it to work in the current ul? (if I add another ul it selects in the first ul)

Comment: After the first one.. not nested :)

Answer (score 4):

Pretty basic:

```
    $('#checkall').click(function(){

       //select ul
       $(this).closest('ul')

        //find checkbox
        .find('> li > input[type=checkbox]') //or : input[type=checkbox]

         //not first check - is the 'select all'
        .not(':first')

         //set value
        .prop('checked', this.checked)
    });
```

Or short:

```
$('#checkall').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('ul').find('> li > input[type=checkbox]').not(':first').prop('checked', this.checked)
});
```